# Open sbt in a subproject

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to open sbt directly in a subproject?

I'm aware that you can do `sbt ";project mysubproject ;run"`, but this does not allow interactions with sbt after the `run`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your operations into steps

```
sbt
project mysubproject
run
```

**EDIT**

Go to interactive mode of child directly

`sbt ";project mysubproject; shell"`